# Retrieving the last record of grouped records using rails 3 using scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having an issue in using group by and order by in one statement in Rails 3

In my controller:

```
def index
  @units = Unit.list_order.grouped
end
```

and my model:

```
scope :list_order, order("units.interior_code, units.created_at ASC")
scope :grouped, group("units.unit_parent")
```

The query is pulling back the data grouped (Unique records are displayed based on unit_parent) and is ordered by interior_code but it's not ordering the grouped records by date, i.e. there may be 4 grouped records and the query does not respect the date ordering to pull only the last record from the group

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group) post on SO which is a similar issue

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `units.created_at` is being ordered as a string, rather than a date, the order won't appear to be correct. Are you sure that the values for `created_at` are being treated as a date?

Comment: created_at is a date/time format in the database, I wasn't aware that it needs to be treated any differently when using order_by.  I got this to work (I think, need to test properly) Unit.find_by_sql('SELECT u1.* FROM units u1 LEFT JOIN units u2 ON (u1.unit_parent = u2.unit_parent AND u1.created_at < u2.created_at) WHERE u2.created_at IS NULL ORDER BY interior_code') but it's very ugly!!!